# Ошибка: 2: error: expression syntax error

Tags: ассемблер, синтаксис

Когда пытаюсь оттранслировать программу в `nasm` выходит вот такая строчка:

> 2: error: expression syntax error

Насколько я понимаю, это ошибка во второй строке программы.
Строка выглядит так:

```
"TAB"hello:"TAB"DB ’Hello world!’,10"TАB";
```

Что у меня не так? В чем проблема? Естественно, вместо "TАB" я просто нажимала клавишу TАB.

Comment: Может быть, вы использовали типографские кавычки (`’`) вместо обычных (`'`)?

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Отлично, перенесу в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы использовали типографские кавычки (`’`) вместо обычных (`'`).

NASM «понимает» только обычные кавычки.

Comment: Еще бы метку у вопроса вменяемую поставили.

Comment: @Visman: Угу, поменял.